# compound interest program problem in dev c++ using c

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am trying to write a program to print simple interest and compound interest in dev c++ in c programming but it is not printing the correct compound interest can anybody tell why?
here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
int p,r,t,si,ci;
printf("enter the principle:");
scanf("%d",&p);
printf("enter the rate:");
scanf("%d",&r);
printf("enter the time:");
scanf("%d",&t);
si=p*r*t/100;
ci=p*pow((1+(r/100)),t);
printf("simple interest:%d",si);
printf("\ncompound interest:%d",ci);
int a=getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems you are doing integer calculations for something that requires floating point calculations

Comment: Are you sure all of the variables should be integers?

Comment: For instance.. `r/100` will give the result 0 (zero) when `r` has a value below 100. Probably not what you want. Consider using the type `double` instead.

Comment: Don't forget to check the return of `scanf()` and there is no `getch()` in C unless you include the non-standard ancient DOS header `conio.h`. (use `getchar()` instead)

Comment: And when you change to `double` use `%lf` instead of `%d`

Answer (score 0):

You have given int instead of float.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    float p,r,t,si,ci;
    printf("enter the principle:");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    printf("enter the rate:");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("enter the time:");
    scanf("%d",&t);
    si=p*r*t/100;
    ci=p*pow((1+(r/100)),t);
    printf("simple interest:%d",si);
    printf("\ncompound interest:%d",ci);
    int a=getch();
    return 0;
}
```